# Register collection of services in MVC Core DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I`ve got simple class with strategies.

```
 public class LinkQualifier : ILinkQualifier
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<IQualifier> _qualifiers;

        public LinkQualifier(IEnumerable<IQualifier> qualifiers)
        {
            _qualifiers = qualifiers;
        }

        public IQualifier Qualify(Uri uri)
        {
            return _qualifiers.FirstOrDefault(q => q.CanQualify(uri));
        }


    }
```

How i can register it in MVC core DI container? I invented something like this:

```
services.AddTransient<ILinkQualifier, LinkQualifier>((ctx =>
            {
                var qualifiers = new List<IQualifier> {...};
                return new LinkQualifier(qialifiers);
            }));
```

But thats looks badly... is there a better solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Register the multiple implementations with the `ServiceCollection`.

The `IEnumerable<IQualifier>` dependency will be recognized by the DI container and will pass all registered implementations.

```
services.AddTransient<IQualifier, QualifierOne>();
services.AddTransient<IQualifier, QualifierTwo>();
services.AddTransient<IQualifier, QualifierThree>();

services.AddTransient<ILinkQualifier, LinkQualifier>();
```

> It’s worth making it clear that the implementations will be added in the order they are registered. They will be returned in that same order when injected into calling code. Depending on your requirements, this may be useful and important.
>
> Reference [ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection – Registering Multiple Implementations of an Interface](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-registering-multiple-implementations-interface)

Comment: Wow! Thats really cool. If create service extention for registering IQuantifier collection, thats looks great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption your `IEnumerable<IQualifier>` may come from something other than a generated / constructed list.
In which case, you could create an interface, and implementation, that returns the `IEnumerable<IQualifier>`

```
public interface IQualifiersProvider
{
    IEnumerable<IQualifier> GetQualifiers();
}

public class QualifiersProvider : IQualifiersProvider
{
    //from db / whatever
    public IEnumerable<IQualifier> GetQualifiers()
    {
        return new [] {
            new Qualifier(),
            new Qualifier(),
        }
    }
}
```

Change your `LinkQualifier` to take a dependency on `IQualifiersProvider`

```
public class LinkQualifier : ILinkQualifier
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IQualifier> _qualifiers;

    public LinkQualifier(IQualifiersProvider qualifiersProvider)
    {
        _qualifiers = qualifiersProvider.GetQualifiers();
    }

    public IQualifier Qualify(Uri uri)
    {
        return _qualifiers.FirstOrDefault(q => q.CanQualify(uri));
    }
}
```

Now register these separately

```
services.AddTransient<IQualifiersProvider, QualifiersProvider>();
services.AddTransient<ILinkQualifier, LinkQualifier>();
```