# How Can I Inject All my Strategy Pattern Objects Into a List?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, strategy-pattern

I've implemented the strategy pattern. I have a base interface, and will be selecting which implementation of this interface I will be using at runtime. The problem is, I don't know of an elegant way that I can populate an object to store all my implementations without hardcoding them (new-ing them up) as such:

```
public class FixMessageFormatter
{
    List<IMessageFormat> _messageFormats = new List<IMessageFormat>{ new MassQuoteMessageFormat(), }
    // ... Other code.
}
```

This is not elegant. If I have over 50 implementations of the `IMessageFormat`, this can get ugly quickly. I've heard of dependency injection, but was unsure of how I'd apply it to this simple example.

For context, the following is my interface, and a single implementation.

**Interface**

```
    public interface IMessageFormat
    {
        List<FixMessageType> MessageType { get; }
        bool IsProperType(FixMessageType fixMessageType);
        StringBuilder FormatMessage(FixMessage fixMessage);
    }
```

**Implementation**

```
    public class MassQuoteMessageFormat : IMessageFormat
    {
        public List<FixMessageType> MessageType => new List<FixMessageType>{ FixMessageType.MassQuote };

        public StringBuilder FormatMessage(FixMessage fixMessage)
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            // ... Code
            return stringBuilder;
        }

        public bool IsProperType(FixMessageType fixMessageType)
        {
            return MessageType.Contains(fixMessageType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this answers your question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428329/1565525](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428329/1565525)

Answer (score 0):

Register each implementation during startup, mapping them with the abstraction,

*ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)*

```
services.AddScoped<IMessageFormat, MassQuoteMessageFormat>(); //<-- or other lifetime scope
//add other implementation...
//they could be done via reflection to auto register.

services.AddScoped<FixMessageFormatter>(); //also adding target
```

and inject an `IEnumerable<IMessageFormat>` into the target dependent instance.

```
public class FixMessageFormatter {
    private List<IMessageFormat> _messageFormats;

    public FixMessageFormatter (IEnumerable<IMessageFormat> formats) {
        _messageFormats = formats.ToList();
    }

    // ... Other code.
}
```

The DI container will inject all registered implementations.

Reference [Logging in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/)

Comment: What is `services` referring to? How will it associate the abstraction IMessageFormat, MassQuoteMessageFormat with `_messageFormats`?
Can it be injected into `FixMessageFormatter` if it is a static class? Can you refer me to some more documentation?

Comment: @TeeZadAwk Added link to documentation. This wont work by default for statis classes, you would have to revert to service locator anti-pattern, and it is not usually advised to take that approach

Comment: I'm still having problems with this. What do I do with the `private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method? Where do I call it? How is the FIxMessageFormatter class created with this enumerable injected?